# RejectedExecutionException while submitting task to ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, junit

spring **ThreadPoolTaskExecutor** for concurrent processing in our application. After successfully completing all the jobs the showdown methods  is called. This implementation is working fine, issue come when the junit is executed.

I have written multiple test cases for this class using **SpringJUnit4ClassRunner**. The first test case will run perfectly and shutdown the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. But when the second test case is trying to submit the task the below exception is raised

```
org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@16cefa8] did not accept task: com.sample.SampleJob@ea3cdf
    ....
aused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:767)
```

Based on my analyis the exception is thrown because i am trying to submit the task to ThreadPoolExecutor when it is shutdown.

Can any one help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: The first step in resolution would be to find out why the `ThreadPoolExecutor` was shutdown!?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when you shutdown the executor but I think shutdown shouldn't be called after every test case but it should be called at the end of all test cases. you can use follwoing:

```
@AfterClass
public void tearDown(){
 //shutdown your executor
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` by default doesn't re-create application context after execution of each test method.

It means that if your `Executor` is declared in the context and you shut in down after execution of a test method you won't be able to use it in other test methods.

You can annotate your test methods with [`@DirtiesContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) to make `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` re-create the context.